# R: object y not found in function (x,y) [function to pass through data frames in r]

Tags: r, dataframe

I am writing a function to build new data frames based on existing data frames. So I essentially have

```
f1 <- function(x,y) {

x_adj <- data.frame("DID*"= df.y$`DM`[x], "LDI"= df.y$`DirectorID*`[-(x)], "LDM"= df.y$`DM`[-(x)], "IID*"=y)

}
```

I have 4,000 data frames df., so I really need to use this and R is returning an error saying that df.y is not found. y is meant to be used through a list of all the 4000 names of the different df. I am very new at R so any help would be really appreciated.

In case more specifics are needed I essentially have something like

```
df.1 <- data.frame(x = 1:3, b = 5)
```

And I need the following as a result using a function

```
df.11 <- data.frame(x = 1, c = 2:3, b = 5)
df.12 <- data.frame(x = 2, c = c(1,3), b = 5)
df.13 <- data.frame(x = 3, c = 1:2, b = 5)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm unclear on what the inputs are supposed to be. Is `df.y` in the global environment? It should be an argument to your function. Or do you have 4000 `df.number` in the global environment right now? You can't reference them by name in the way you're doing without some hacks, you should put them into a list. How were they created?

Comment: Your code for `f1` makes little sense; (1) What is `df`? Is that defined globally? (2) Column names of `df` are awful. For example `DID*` will automatically become `DID.`; (3) You are selecting different size subsets of column vectors; from the first column you *select* `x` entries; from the second column you *remove* `x` entries; from the last column you select `y` entries. This will not work. Can you clarify on what the function is actually supposed to do?

Comment: Are you trying to get `data.frame` with dynamic name?

Comment: Your question makes me think you want to use "." as a concatenation operator in R. Not going to work. Also makes me think you intend to form object names on the left side of "$". Also not going to succeed. You will need to learn a new language and give you your preconceptions formed from whatever leads you to these guesses about R's syntax.

Answer (score 0):

OP seems to access `data.frame` with dynamic name.

One option is to use `get`:

```
get(paste("df",y,sep = "."))
```

The above `get` will return `df.1`.

Hence, the function can be modified as:

```
f1 <- function(x,y) {
  temp_df <- get(paste("df",y,sep = "."))
  x_adj <- data.frame("DID*"= temp_df$`DM`[x], "LDI"= temp_df$`DirectorID*`[-(x)],
  "LDM"= temp_df$`DM`[-(x)], "IID*"=y)

}
```

Comment: I think you should encourage newbies to work with R using lists.